# IL optimization attempt results in slower execution

Tags: c#, optimization, il

Consider this more of an academic question rather than practical.

While reinventing a wheel, that is, writing a mini-ORM/type mapper, I've emitted some IL to convert properties of an object into SqlParameters that are added to a SqlCommand.

My first attempt was basically to write the C# code and translate it into IL 1:1, resulting in the following code (which works flawlessly). Note that comments denote the stack after running the following emitted IL:

```
int paramLocIndex = localIndex++;

 // Get the type handler [typeHandler]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ClrTypeHandlers[prop.PropertyType].GetType().GetMethod("GetTypeHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));

// Load the object [typeHandler, object]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);

// Get the property value [typeHandler, value]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, prop.GetMethod);

// Box the value [typeHandler, boxedValue]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, prop.PropertyType);

// Let the type handler create the param [param]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(SqlTypeHandler).GetMethod("CreateParamFromValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(object) }, null));

// Store the parameter as a variable []
il.DeclareLocal(typeof(SqlParameter));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, paramLocIndex);

// Load the parameter again [param]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, paramLocIndex);

// Load the parameter name [param, paramName]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, paramName);

// Set the parameter name []
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(SqlParameter).GetMethod("set_ParameterName"));

// Load the command [cmd]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

// Load the parameter collection [paramCollection]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(SqlCommand).GetMethod("get_Parameters"));

// Load the parameter [paramCollection, param]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, paramLocIndex);

// Add the parameter to the collection [param]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(SqlParameterCollection).GetMethod("Add", new[] { typeof(SqlParameter) }));

// Get rid of the added parameter, as returned by SqlParameterCollection.Add []
il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
```

While the above works, I wanted to try to optimize it. This resulted in the following code, which also works flawlessly:

```
// Load the command [cmd]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

// Load the parameter collection [paramCollection]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(SqlCommand).GetMethod("get_Parameters"));

// Get the type handler [paramCollection, typeHandler]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ClrTypeHandlers[prop.PropertyType].GetType().GetMethod("GetTypeHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));

// Load the object [paramCollection, typeHandler, object]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);

// Get the property value [paramCollection, typeHandler, value]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, prop.GetMethod);

// Box the value [paramCollection, typeHandler, boxedValue]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, prop.PropertyType);

// Let the type handler create the param [paramCollection, param]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(SqlTypeHandler).GetMethod("CreateParamFromValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(object) }, null));

// Add the parameter to the collection [param]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(SqlParameterCollection).GetMethod("Add", new[] { typeof(SqlParameter) }));

// Load the parameter name [param, paramName]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, paramName);

// Set the parameter name []
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(SqlParameter).GetMethod("set_ParameterName"));
```

While the optimized attempt results in way fewer instructions, avoiding variables, etc. it still runs slower. The first attempt runs in 21500 ticks while the "optimized" version runs in 75000 ticks.

Both of these are plenty fast, but I am curious as to why the first one runs so much faster. I know there's a second level of compilation from IL to machine code - and the answer probably lies in the optimizations performed by the IL compiler. The question is, what are my options if I want to explore this further? Any obvious reasons why the second IL attempt runs slower?

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Shiva Ah, wasn't aware of that one. If a mod can move it, that'd be great :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with IL compilation optimizations but is related to the rather more boring way that the framework handles adding to the SqlParameterCollection.

In the first (longer) method you:

- Create the SqlParameter
- Assign its property name
- Add it to the collection

In the optimized version you:

- Create the SqlParameter
- Add it to the collection
- Assign its property name

Notice the difference? The last 2 steps are transposed it seems rather academic but if you fire up reflector and look at the SqlParameterCollection source you stumble upon this bit of code:

```
private void Validate(int index, object value)
{
    /* snip */
    if (((SqlParameter) value).ParameterName.Length == 0)
    {
        string str;
        index = 1;
        do
        {
            str = "Parameter" + index.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            index++;
        }
        while (-1 != this.IndexOf(str));
        ((SqlParameter) value).ParameterName = str;
    }
}
```

When you add it to the collection without the parameter name one gets generated for it and this process involves assignments, loops and lookups into the list which should easily account for the extra running time you have noticed.

If you are trying to avoid creating a local variable SqlTypeHandler seems to be a class that you control? So you could add the parameter name as an argument to the CreateParamFromValue method and assign it in there so when its added to the collection it already has a name.

Comment: This definitely sounds like what's happening. Let me try it out tonight and report back, thanks! :)

Comment: Yup, that did the trick, down to about 20k ticks. Still had hoped for a bigger difference, but this was definitely the reason. Thanks!